# Display the selected value of a Drop down list in a text field (javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu

For Example:
These are the items in a drop down list.

```
<select name="cmbitems" id="cmbitems">
    <option value="price1">blue</option>
    <option value="price2">green</option>
    <option value="price3">red</option>
</select>
```

When the user selects blue, i want to display the value of price1 in a text field below:

```
<input type="text" name="txtprice" id="txtprice" onClick="checkPrice()">
```

Thank you for answering

Comment: if you feel that any answer solve your problems please tag it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is set the value of the input to the value of the select, in a select.onchange event handler.

```
var select = document.getElementById('cmbitems');
var input = document.getElementById('txtprice');
select.onchange = function() {
    input.value = select.value;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jumpnett/jNGWX/) is a link to a jsFiddle demo

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/val/) just go with

```
$('select.foo option:selected').val();    // get the value from a dropdown select
```

**UPDATE  ( I forgot to inlcude the `<input>` population)**

First, inlcude jquery in your html file.

In the `<header>` you include it:

```
<header>
<script type="text/javascript" src="YOUR_PATH_TO_LIBRARY/jquery-1.7.1-min.js"></script>
</header>
```

Then

```
<input type="text" name="txtprice" id="txtprice" onClick="javascript:$('select.foo option:selected').val();">
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention in javascript

Comment: This will only give you the value of the selected element(s).. not populate them in the input. Check my answer below for more details.

Comment: jquery is a javascript library created to make your life easier! Have a look at it and then you'll discover a whole new - simplier - way of coding.

Answer (score 1):

This is the brute force way to look up the currently selected option, check its value and use its display text to update your input. Like Daniele suggested, if you have jquery at your disposal, this gets much, much easier. But if you can't use a JS framework for any reason, this should get you what you need.

```
<select name="cmbitems" id="cmbitems" onchange="updateTextField()">
 ...
</select>
<input type="text" ..... />

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTextField()
{
    var select = document.getElementById("cmbitems");
    var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    if (option.id == "price1")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtprice").value = option.text;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.on('change', '#cmbitems', function() {
    $('#txtprice').val($('#cmbitems option:selected').val());
});
```